# Thread removing from arrayList and function inserting

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, arraylist

As title states I have problem with thread based structure. What I need to do is:

- one thread running in loop and checking if there exists something in list and if so then performing some operation on object and then removing it from list
- function which is called from 'outside' and adding new objects to this list.

here is my approach:

```
public class Queue implements Runnable {
    private List<X> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<X>;

    public void addToList(X toAdd){
        listOfObject.add(toAdd);
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true){
            synchronized(listOfObjects){
            if(!listOfObjects.isEmpty()){
                listOfObjects.get(0).doSth();
                listOfObjects.remove(0);
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it proper approach? Should I also synchronize adding to this list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you should try an implementation of [java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html), rather than try and write your own! I suspect a [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) will work nicely for you. You can write entries into the queue from multiple sources, and your consumer thread will take each entry off and process it in turn, in a thread-safe fashion.

Note that your consumer thread for a `BlockingQueue` will *wait* (by calling the `take()` method). Your implementation above, however, will spin and consume CPU whilst waiting for entries to be processed in the queue (this should be evident if you run it and monitor your CPU usage).

Here's [an explanatory article](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/blockingqueue.html).

Comment: what happens if I have quite long queue to process ? Is adding new elements blocked until all elements are processed?

Comment: You can specify size in the constructor and then producer blocks if Queue is full. That is called Bounded Queues.

Comment: You can configure that with some implementations of the blocking queue, I think. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html for example

Comment: @xwhyz Read the linked javadocs, especially the part in `LinkedBlockingQueue` on the capacity.

Answer (score 1):

You need to synchronize all accesses to your list:

```
public void addToList(X toAdd){
    synchronized(listOfObject) {
        listOfObject.add(toAdd);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could use a thread safe implementation of List such a [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html), in which case you can remove all the `synchronized` blocks.

ps: as mentioned in another answer, you seeem to be reimplementing an [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use `Collections.synchronizedList()` wrapper instead of  a manually synchronized block.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are trying to create a queue for a thread to process elements added.

A simpler approach is to use an ExecutorService.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadedPool();

// to add a task.
service.submit(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       // process X here
    }
});
```